# PlatformException(invalid_image, Cannot load representation of type public.jpeg, NSItemProviderErrorDomain, null)

Tags: ios, flutter

I am getting folowing error for image_picker flutter implementaion

```
PlatformException(invalid_image, Cannot load representation of type public.jpeg, NSItemProviderErrorDomain, null)
```

this issue happening on ios simulator

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**yes this happens when you try to choose a corrupted image in ios simulator,**

**to solve this just choose another image or download some images from safari
browser**

Comment: i tried the default images in simulator

Comment: yes exactly they are corrupted try other images they will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "erasing all contents and settings" on the simulator helped me!

Comment: Is there any workaround? 
It happens for me on a real device

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this similar issue on iOS simulator, right after upgrading the `image_picker` package.

I downgraded it to `image_picker: ^0.8.7`. It started working for me normally.

[image_picker (pub.dev)](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)